# How to achieve master pages / templating in the html5/jquery world

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm working on a greenfield web app. We're evaluating technologies such as htlm5/jquery/backbone.js talking to a RESTful web service.

For page 1, this is fine. For page 2, I don't want to copy and paste anything. In the ASP.NET world, I would use Master Pages bring in the  and  definitions, headers, footers etc.

Is there a javascript/client-side approach to master-pages?

Comment: do a google search for "javascript templating" and pick one that meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to do this in HTML5:

1. Using `<iframe>`
2. Using `JavaScript`

Since `<iframe>` is an outdated concept, using JavaScript is recommended.

For more information please have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114458/Master-Pages-using-HTML-and-JavaScript).